# KVM redirected USB disk not visible in guest

Tags: usb, kubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I have:

- host: Kubuntu 18.04 fresh install + kvm + virt-manager
- guest: Kubuntu 18.04 fresh install

I plug an external drive in host and it is visible in `sudo lsusb`

In virt-manager for a vm I select the disk from the menu "virtual machine" -> "USB device redirection" popup window.

The disk is visible and selectable.

But inside the VM the disk is not visible also `sudo lsusb` do not show any disk

Tried the operations with the VM turned off and the VM turned on: nothing changes

What can I do?

Comment: I must admit the menu is disabled for me, but to check the base tech I used a 18.04 host/guest and added a fingerprint reader by [xml-definition](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ws4Zzt6XQd/) via `virsh attach-device b1 usb.xml` just fine. You might want to check in your case the guest (/var/log/libvirt/qemu/<guestname>.log) log as well as dmesg if you hit anything preventing the passthrough.